# How do you access the in-memory neo4j driver using the JavaScript implementation?

Tags: javascript, neo4j

The neo4j Java driver has access to an in-memory driver that's handy for unit testing. For example, see [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/blob/master/neo4j-jdbc-bolt/src/test/java/org/neo4j/jdbc/bolt/SampleIT.java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628313/neo4j-unit-testing-the-bolt-driver-properly#37640278). Does the official JavaScript driver have a similar tool? If so, how is it accessed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such tool for Javascript or any other non-jvm language. Also the example you show is not used for unit testing but for Integration Testing, hence the `IT` at the end of the class names.

There are lot of ways to do Integration Tests between your javascript application and a neo4j database.

1. Simply use a neo4j instance on your local machine
2. Spin up a docker neo4j instance : https://neo4j.com/developer/docker/
3. Create a javascript package doing assertions against your graph, as an example in PHP : https://github.com/graphaware/php-graphunit/blob/master/src/Neo4jGraphDatabaseTestCase.php#L68
4. Use a neo4j plugin that provides useful REST endpoints for integration testing : https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-resttest
5. If you use travis, spin up a neo4j instance, for example using build scripts : https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/tree/master/build
6. Create your own in-memory/impermanent graph database services (more hardcore to do though) : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole
7. `<insert other here>`

Comment: Great, thanks for all the different strategies! Using a local instance as a throw away makes a lot of sense. The in-memory feature seems cool though, that's too bad.

Comment: Well the in-memory actually spins up an graph database but with an Impermanent storage, I will amend my answer with an example of such usage