# Sending JSON and status code with a Flask response

Tags: json, flask

I know I can set the status code of a response with `Response(status=200)`. How can I return JSON data while setting the status code?

```
from flask import Flask, Response

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    response = Response(status=200)
    # need to set JSON like {'username': 'febin'}
    return response
```

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Use [`flask.jsonify()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.json.jsonify). This method takes any serializable data type. For example I have used a dictionary `data` in the following example.

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = {'name': 'nabin khadka'}
    return jsonify(data)
```

To return a status code, return a tuple of the response and code:

```
return jsonify(data), 200
```

Note that 200 is the default status code, so it's not necessary to specify that code.

---

### UPDATE

As of **Flask 1.1**, the return statement will automatically `jsonify` a dictionary in the first return value. You can return the data directly:

```
return data
```

You can also return it with a status code:

```
return data, 200
```

Answer (score 23):

You can append the data to the response like this:

```
from flask import Flask, json

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    data = {"some_key":"some_value"} # Your data in JSON-serializable type
    response = app.response_class(response=json.dumps(data),
                                  status=200,
                                  mimetype='application/json')
    return response
```

The response data content type is defined by mimetype parameter.