# How to return a json file without save on disk via flask?

Tags: python, json, flask

Here I have a dict,

```
dict1 = {'name':"max","age":20}
```

What I want to do is to save the dict into a json file.

```
@bp_main.route('/download/json', methods=['GET'])
def get_sample_json_file():
    dict1 =  {'name':"max","age":20}
    return ???
```

What I did now, is to save dict1 into a real json file, and use flask send_from_directory to return the file. How to avoid saving dict1 into disk?

Comment: Have you tried `import json; ...; json.dumps(dict1)` to represent the `dict1` as a JSON-string?

Comment: Why send directory, instead just return the json.

Answer (score 2):

This will just return the dictionary what you have and by that you don't have to save dictionary to file.

```
from flask import Response
import json


@bp_main.route('/download/json', methods=['GET'])
def get_sample_json_file():
    dict1 =  {'name':"max","age":20}
    return Response(json.dumps(dict1), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
```

You can also try [jsonify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412228/sending-json-and-status-code-with-a-flask-response/45412576#45412576) response. But I prefer `Response` way.